# problema con los Header, Angular 6, HttpClient

Tags: angular, api, ionic

tengo problemas al intentar consumir una api en angular

resulta que para buscar en la api necesito enviar un header con la clave "producto" y el valor que deseo buscar, en la web funciona bien.

lo deseo hacer en angular pero solo recibo errores, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
buscarProductos(term: string){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      });

      this.http.post(apiUrl+'busqueda', {}, {headers}).subscribe((res) => {
        resolve(res);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

en el postman seria asi:

[image: captura de postman]

que me estaria faltando? he intentado agregar una linea mas en header asi:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'producto':term
      });
```

pero no funciono, tambien cree una variable data asi:

```
let data = {"producto":term};
```

y lo mande asi:

```
this.http.post(apiUrl+'busqueda', {data}, {headers}).subscribe((res) => {
        resolve(res);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
```

pero tampoco funciono, no se q podria estar faltando... gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Sin saber el error poco te podemos decir. Supongo que no podrás hacer peticiones cruzadas (CORS) entre dominios.

Comment: Supongo que no tendrás el código tal cual, pero hay una errata en la creación de headers, con un punto donde debería haber una coma

Comment: no es cors, ya tengo otras llamadas sin parámetro si que si los trae sin problema, voy a poner el error ahora

Comment: pablo tienes razon, fue error de escritura, en el codigo es una coma, gracias por la observación

Comment: servira si les doy acceso al repositorio?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mostrar una foto/mensaje del error?

En todo caso prueba con otro header content-type, ya que al parecer recibes una respuesta en formato JSON.

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type','application/json'); //o setItem()
let params = new HttpParams();
params.set('producto', 'term');
```

Y después para la request haces:

```js
this.http.post(apiUrl+'busqueda', {headers: headers, params: params}).subscribe((res) => {
  resolve(res);
}, (err) => {
  reject(err);
});
```